# latter codes excutes first in java/android

Tags: java, android

```
if(b){ 
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);
    tv.setText("Right!");
    check.setClickable(false);
    check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    safe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.safe_opened);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finish();
}
```

If I am right, this `Activity` will execute the code from top to bottom (hide keyboard, disable buttons, etc).

However, when I run this app on my phone, it waits for 1000 milliseconds, and then sets the text to `"Right!"`, changes backgrounds, etc..

I think the code is executed from bottom to top. I searched for answers but nothing came up. Why does this thing happen?

Comment: You're right about the order of execution, however you're missing a key element here - the results will be displayed after the method finishes (nothing is rendered until then). However, your `Thread.sleep` is done on the UI thread, thus keeping the method from executing and allowing the operating system to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does run from top to bottom, but issue here is that by the time UI tries to refresh it and set the text "Right!" to the `TextView`, you ask the UI thread to sleep for 1000 millisecond. During that time you won't see any rendering. All the rendering or UI changes happens after that. It's not like you do `tv.setText("Right!");` or `safe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.safe_opened);` and it will happen instantly. These things forces UI to re-render itself which takes little bit of time (negligible to human). Before Framework could refresh the UI, you asked it to wait which is causing the delay in applying those changes to UI you asked for.

**Note:** It's never a good idea to force UI thread to sleep. If you need to wait for some operation and then apply the changes yo should use `Thread` and `Handler` or may be `AsyncTask` as per you needs.